# Using django-autocomplete-light in grappelli in a stackedinline form

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to use django-autocomplete-light in a grappelli admin page within a `StackedInline`.

When used on fields in the main model, `autocomplete-light` fields work perfectly fine.

[image]

However in inlines they are non-functional. All I get is a gray X, that doesn't remove the model, and no field to enter text into:

[image]

And in dynamically added inlines, I can't even click into the field!:

[image]

My code:

In `admin.py`

```
class ServiceInline(MembershipInline):
    model = models.Service
    form = forms.MembershipInlineFormFactory(models.Service)
```

In `forms.py`

```
class ServiceAutocompleteForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields='__all__'
        model = models.Service

        autocomplete_fields  = ['person','position']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out this is an issue with the generated CSS, where a float in grappelli is covering the actual autocomplete inputs. This can be fixed with the following CSS rule (as long as this is included in a file used by the admin site):

```
.autocomplete-light-widget {
  z-index:10;
}
```